# Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry

Tags: quarkus, testcontainers

I am using quarkus 2.16.6 Final on macos intel chip.

After some time i am getting error from devservices `Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry.`

Docker is running and I am able to create container.

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have docker installed on your machine?

Comment: Can you try `echo $DOCKER_HOST` and add result to question please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issue with the Test container of  quarkus 2.16.6.
Use 2.15.0.Final version.